# Python - how to extract multiple Json files from Json list

Tags: python, json

Have a json contain list of dictionaries as following:

```
[
  {
    "native_data": {
      "PopOrGuess": null,
      "role": "D",
      "TSX": "Included"
    },
    "id": "3dsdsa_a_12sss"
  },
  {
    "native_data": {
      "PopOrGuess": 123,
      "role": "A",
      "TSX": "NA"
    },
    "id": "12_123_saba"
  }
]
```

I need to extract this list and create new json file per element in list,
so file_name will get the "id" value ,and the json content the first element in dict,
meaning for first element "id": "12_123_saba"
file name: 3dsdsa_a_12sss.json

```
{
    "native_data": {
      "PopOrGuess": null,
      "role": "D",
      "TSX": "Included"
    }
  }
```

I tried :

```
def ExtractJsonPrice( file ):
    jsonFile = open(file, "r") # Open the JSON file for reading
    try:
       json_data = json.load(jsonFile)
    except ValueError:
           print("error loading JSON")
           logging.error("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
    
    for item in json_data:
        file_name = item['id']
        json_content = item['native_data']
```

and from there i have the file name ,
but the problem , the json_content holds now the content of the key of 'native_data'
but it actually missing the KEY "native_data",
I guess I could append it as post process but im sure there's more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

yes you are getting the key, you can do this,

```
json_content = {'native_data': item['native_data']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way:

```
    
    for item in json_data:
        json_content = {}
        file_name = item['id']
        json_content["native_data"]= item['native_data'] 
        file_name = list(item.values())[1]
        
        with open('ID_' + file_name + '.json' , 'w') as fp:  
             json.dump(json_content,fp)
```